# Sharepoint 2013 on premise NewForm on list javascript logic not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, validation, sharepoint-2013

[Screen shot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udADv.png)ok so i have some code that i thought was correct but for some reason it is not being triggered,  what i need is the save button to be disabled until all 5 of these question are ticked and = true but for some reason at this point nothing happens as the save button is not disabled when the form loads and i can submit a form with none of these ticked and they are all checkboxes.  I have tried adding this text to CEWP and a SEWP but nothing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script language="javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Disable the "Save" button initially
    var Checkbox1 = $("input[title='Question A']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox2 = $("input[title='Question B']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox3 = $("input[title='Question C']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox4 = $("input[title='Question D']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox5 = $("input[title='Question E']").attr('disabled', true);
 
 
 //Enable-Disable "Save" button based on "I Agree" checkbox value!
   var Checkbox1 = $("input[title='Question A']").click(function()
   var Checkbox2 = $("input[title='Question B']").click(function()
   var Checkbox3 = $("input[title='Question C']").click(function()
   var Checkbox4 = $("input[title='Question D']").click(function()
   var Checkbox5 = $("input[title='Question E']").click(function()(
        if(this.checked)
           {
            $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', false);
           }      
        else
           {
            $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', true);  
           }
     }); 
 
  });
 
</script>
```

Comment: Is jquery loading? Try adding an alert or console message to check this.

Comment: after having a look in chrome it looks like my company has blocked it not sure how to get around this see sscreen shot link at the top of this page

Comment: You can add the script file in the site assets to avoid loading it over cdn. Alternatively, you could try loading the script via a secure `https` cdn. Have you tried changing the source to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js` (added "s")?

Comment: I have tried adding script file to site assets then used a link in a CEWP and also tried adding https to the link as suggested but again nothing looks like its not beingtriggered at all

Comment: Ok now got it working as in the save button is disabled when the form loads, but now when i have ticked the boxes required it doesn't enable the save button for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error, a lot of brackets, braces are missing.I’m not sure if the logic is correct. I correct the grammatical error first. You could have a try.

```
<script language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    //Disable the "Save" button initially
    var Checkbox1 = $("input[title='Question A']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox2 = $("input[title='Question B']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox3 = $("input[title='Question C']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox4 = $("input[title='Question D']").attr('disabled', true);
    var Checkbox5 = $("input[title='Question E']").attr('disabled', true);


    //Enable-Disable "Save" button based on "I Agree" checkbox value!
    var Checkbox1 = $("input[title='Question A']").click(function () {
      var Checkbox2 = $("input[title='Question B']").click(function () {
        var Checkbox3 = $("input[title='Question C']").click(function () {
          var Checkbox4 = $("input[title='Question D']").click(function () {
            var Checkbox5 = $("input[title='Question E']").click(function () {
              if (this.checked) {
                $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', false);
              }
              else {
                $("input[value$='Save']").attr('disabled', true);
              }
            })
          })
        })
      })

    })
  }); 
</script>
```